# how to know which word version is installed from my add-in (Ribbon)? with c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I build add-in for word with c#.
my add-in can work on word 2010 and 2013. how to know which word version is installed from my add-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using VSTO, you can read the `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version` property (see [MSDN Blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/04/creating-an-add-in-for-office-2007-and-office-2010-that-quot-lights-up-quot-on-office-2010-mclean-schofield.aspx)).

```
string version = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Version;
string majorStr = version.Split('.').First();
int major = Convert.ToInt32(majorStr);

if (major == 14)         // Word 2010
    // ...
else if (major == 15)    // Word 2013
    // ...
```